JAVA. проблема с блоками кода
Учу JAVA на практикуме, не могу понять. Где-то ошибаюсь с блоками. Поддержка мурыжит голову. Помогите пожалуйста, где ошибка у меня
class WashingModeDetector {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int dirtyLevel = 3;
    boolean isDelicate = true;
    int clothesWeight = 6;

    String washingMode; 

    if (dirtyLevel <= 2) {
      if (isDelicate == true) {
      washingMode = "Деликатный";
    } else {
      washingMode = "Стандартный";
    }
   }   
    if (clothesWeight > 5) {
      washingMode = "Большая загрузка"; {
        else {
      washingMode = "Сильные загрязнения"; }
      
      System.out.println("Выбран режим стирки: " + washingMode)
    }
  }
}

}

class WashingModeDetector {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int dirtyLevel = 3;
    boolean isDelicate = true;
    int clothesWeight = 6;

    String washingMode; 

    if (dirtyLevel <= 2) {
      if (isDelicate == true) {
      washingMode = "Деликатный";
    } else {
      washingMode = "Стандартный";
    }
   } else {  
      if (clothesWeight > 5) {
      {
      washingMode = "Большая загрузка"; }
        else {
      washingMode = "Сильные загрязнения"; }
      }
      System.out.println("Выбран режим стирки: " + washingMode);
    }   
  }
}

Вот мой код. В комментариях напишу их помощь по коду
з.ы. сделал все, как они и говорили
Ошибка та же : java:19: error: 'else' without 'if'

Похожий вопрос о том же классе Как к переменной "String washingMode;" присвоить значение из выполненного действия?

Вот поэтому люди и пользуются IDE, чтобы анализаторы подобные вещи подсвечивали сразу и не приходилось ломать голову.

Итого у вас после if сразу две открывающих скобки, из-за чего и вышел повисший непонятно где else. Убрана лишняя двойная скобка в конце if, убрана лишняя закрывающая скобка в конце класса, остальное оставлено как есть.
class WashingModeDetector {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int dirtyLevel = 3;
        boolean isDelicate = true;
        int clothesWeight = 6;

        String washingMode;

        if (dirtyLevel <= 2) {
            if (isDelicate == true) {
                washingMode = "Деликатный";
            } else {
                washingMode = "Стандартный";
            }
        } else {
            if (clothesWeight > 5) {
                washingMode = "Большая загрузка";
            } else {
                washingMode = "Сильные загрязнения";
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Выбран режим стирки: " + washingMode);
    }
}


        if (clothesWeight > 5) {
          washingMode = "Большая загрузка";
        }
        else {
          washingMode = "Сильные загрязнения"; 
        }
          
        System.out.println("Выбран режим стирки: " + washingMode);
      
  


submission/WashingModeDetector.java:21: error: ';' expected
      System.out.println("Выбран режим стирки: " + washingMode)

вот ошибка (

Еще добавьте точку с запятой в конце ashingMode);

"Не хватает ветвления else, в которое будут вложены последние два ветвления if и else, об этом мы писали в предыдущем сообщении.
вот, что практикум пишет! "
Сама прога работает, но не проходит проверку у практикума !
За точку с запятой спасибо, уже такой ерунды сам не заметил ... :)
